# CDI producer fallback (ContextNotActiveException)

Tags: java, cdi

We'd like to use CDI to implement some cross cutting functionality like logging audit information, authorization etc. In order to do that we'd have some bean that contains an injection point for the current user like this:

```
class AuditLogger {
  @Inject
  private Instance<User> currentUser;

  public void log(Whatever data) {
    User userWhoTriggeredIt = currentUser.get();
    ...
  }
}
```

Additionally we have a session scoped user manager bean that contains a producer method:

```
@SessionScoped
class UserManager {
  @Produces
  @Current
  public User getCurrentUser() {
    //get and return the user
  }
}
```

This works fine as long as we have a session context up and running (i.e. within our web application). However, there are situations in which there is no session context, i.e. when certain web services or MBeans are called. In those situations we'd like to have a fallback producer that provides a generic "application" user.

So basically in `AuditLogger` we'd like to get the user from the session scoped `UserManager` unless we're running outside a session in which case we'd use the fallback "application" user.

However, this seems to be somewhat hard using Weld 1.x (we're running in a JBoss 7.2 and can't upgrade right now, although we'd consider that if CDI 1.2 provides a solution).

A few options that we tried so far:

- use `Instance.select( new AnnotationLiteral<Current>() {}).isUnsatisfied()` to check whether there is a producer available. This seems to return false, however, so when we try to call `get()` we still get the `ContextNotActiveException`
- iterate over Instance, i.e. `for( User u : currentUser )`, but since there is no qualifier information it's hard to distinguish the correct one when we have a session (Update: the tests were misleading, we get that exception here as well)
- not tried but it seems possible though somewhat hacky: catch that exception and try the fallback

Any ideas on the canonical/least hacky/error prone way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

As documented in [Obtaining the active Context for a scope](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.1/cdi-spec.html#bm_obtain_active_context), you can write:

```
@Inject
BeanManager bm;

Context context = bm.getContext(SessionScoped.class);
```

Unfortunately, this only permits to retrieve the **active** context and throws a `ContextNotActiveException` exception if no active context object exists for the scope type.

Thus, even though the `Context.isActive()` method exists, it is not possible to reliably check whether a context is active without relying on the `ContextNotActiveException` exception mechanism.

Comment: Hmm, the link seems to point to a wrong part of the 1.1 spec (observer methods) but it seems that we'd need to use the exception. Thanks for the hint, I'll dig a bit more into the spec.

Comment: I've fixed the link. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem :). Regarding `Context.isActive()` - I'd say that method exists for internal purposes, i.e. to enable the container to check whether the context is active or not. From the spec it seems that we'd either have to handle the exception manually or maybe provide a custom injection point (although I'm not sure that would allow us to introduce a fallback mechanism that way)

Comment: Yes, you're right. `Context.isActive()` is more a SPI than an API, to be used by custom context implementations. Though use cases like yours tend to prove that using it as an API would make sense as well and that the current design is asymmetrical. I would question BeanManager.getContext() throwing `ContextNotActiveException`, while `Context.get()` throwing it would be just fine.

Comment: Since version 1.3.0 DeltaSpike has a class [ContextUtils](http://deltaspike.apache.org/javadoc/1.3.0/org/apache/deltaspike/core/util/ContextUtils.html), which basically catches the `ContextNotActiveException` in the method `isContextActive()` and returns false in that case. So handling the exception currently actually seems the way to check the context itself - although I'd prefer some mechanism to provide producer fallbacks in my case, be it in the same or a different context.

Comment: Indeed, that strongly suggests that there is no better way around the `ContextNotActiveException` exception. I would suggest you create an corresponding story in the CDI specfication JIRA:https://issues.jboss.org/browse/CDI to be considered in version 2.0 of the spec that is being worked on.